# How to make API test files with Beego

Tags: postgresql, go, beego

I have below test file:

```
package tests

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
    "runtime"
    "path/filepath"
    _ "hello/routers"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"

    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
    . "github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/convey"
)

func init() {
    _, file, _, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
    apppath, _ := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(filepath.Join(file, ".." + string(filepath.Separator))))
    beego.TestBeegoInit(apppath)
}

// TestGet is a sample to run an endpoint test
func TestGet(t *testing.T) {
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/api/testing", nil)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    beego.BeeApp.Handlers.ServeHTTP(w, r)

    beego.Trace("testing", "TestGet", "Code[%d]\n%s", w.Code, w.Body.String())

    Convey("Subject: Test Station Endpoint\n", t, func() {
            Convey("Status Code Should Be 200", func() {
                    So(w.Code, ShouldEqual, 200)
            })
            Convey("The Result Should Not Be Empty", func() {
                    So(w.Body.Len(), ShouldBeGreaterThan, 0)
            })
    })
}
```

Then when I run `go test tests/*.go`

I get:

```
2015/01/14 23:55:19 [config.go:284] [W] open /home/IdeaProjects/go/src/hello/tests/conf/app.conf: no such file or directory 
[ORM]register db Ping `default`, pq: password authentication failed for user "hello"
must have one register DataBase alias named `default`
FAIL    command-line-arguments  0.008s
```

I've bootstraped Beego with `bee api` then using pq Postgres Driver for PG database.

Also I'm not sure why it's looking at `/hello/tests/conf/app.conf` path for `app.conf` file it should look for `/hello/conf/app.conf`.

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: Hi, did you find out what is going on with the testing? I have a similar problem where my app routes aren't being picked up. Edit: Figured out I needed to import my routes package in the test to pick them up... doh

Comment: I am facing the same issue , it's trying to find the conf inside tests and not the project. Did u find ay resolution @Passionate Developer

Answer (score 0):

PG can't authenticate you probably because it can't find the password in the `app.conf` file, which it also can't find because it's looking in the wrong place.

Try using an absolute path to your config rather than the convoluted method you have in your `init()` function.