# Beego - Endpoint Testing

Tags: go, beego

I am testing http custom endpoint for beego

```
package test

import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
    . "github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/convey"
    _ "golife-api-cons/routers"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
    "testing"
)

func init() {
    _, file, _, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
    apppath, _ := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(filepath.Join(file, ".."+string(filepath.Separator))))
    beego.TestBeegoInit(apppath)
}

// TestGet is a sample to run an endpoint test
func TestGet(t *testing.T) {
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/my/endpoint/fetches/data", nil)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    beego.BeeApp.Handlers.ServeHTTP(w, r)

    beego.Trace("testing", "TestGet", "Code[%d]\n%s", w.Code, w.Body.String())

    Convey("Subject: Test Station Endpoint\n", t, func() {
        Convey("Status Code Should Be 200", func() {
            So(w.Code, ShouldEqual, 200)
        })
        Convey("The Result Should Not Be Empty", func() {
            So(w.Body.Len(), ShouldBeGreaterThan, 0)
        })
    })
}
```

When i run using `go test -v` ,

I get in response `dial tcp :0: getsockopt: connection refused`

I am using MariaDB running on my local, 
I have verified using `netstat -tulpn` that my database is running perfectly fine (I get a valid response if i use postman and my server is running)

One weird observation , after inclusion of line `_ "golife-api-cons/routers"` i get this error even before test's are ran

My test passes with response 200 OK , but without any data as i get in response the above mentioned error

**EDIT**

The default path by used by `TestBeegoInit` function used is `/path/to/my/project/test`
which is not the desired path , so i tried giving the absolute path too , still i am not able to connect DB.

Comment: what settings does your app run with? You say your db is running but how does your test know what db to connect to?

Comment: @dusual - Any specific setting you need ?
Check the like beego.TestBeegoInit(<path/to/config/file>) in source

Answer (score 2):

After much trying I came to know that beego initializes its variable called as `AppPath` in **beego/conf.go** like -

```
AppPath, _ = filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
```

when you run your tests you run them with `go test -v`

but as a result the `os.Args[0]` is the text executable which will be **/tmp/path/to/test** and not **path/to/app/exe**

hence as a result it does not find **config/app.conf** which is in your app path which has db connection details.
Responsible line in **beego/conf.go** -

```
appConfigPath = filepath.Join(AppPath, "conf", "app.conf")
```

This all happens in beego's `init` function when you say

```
import (
  "github.com/astaxie/beego"
  _ "path/to/routers"
)
```

Hack for this is -

create a new package / file with init function which looks has -

```
package common

import (
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func init() {
    cwd := os.Getenv("PWD")
    rootDir := strings.Split(cwd, "tests/")
    os.Args[0] = rootDir[0] // path to you dir
}
```

here you are changing `os.Args[0]` and assigning your directory path

make sure you import it before beego so now import will look like

```
import (
  _ "path/to/common"
  "github.com/astaxie/beego"
  _ "path/to/routers"
)
```

And finally you connect to DB !

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your app as

```
apppath, _ := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(filepath.Join(file, ".."+string(filepath.Separator))))
    beego.TestBeegoInit(apppath)
}
```

Where `file` is the caller file.

TestBeegoInit is:

```
func TestBeegoInit(ap string) {
    os.Setenv("BEEGO_RUNMODE", "test")
    appConfigPath = filepath.Join(ap, "conf", "app.conf")
    os.Chdir(ap)
    initBeforeHTTPRun()
}
```

hence the location where your tests are looking for configuration is

```
<this_file>/../conf/app.conf
```

which basically is the default config file.

Basically you are not able to connect to the database. Perhaps because you are unknowingly connecting to your default database for the tests too. I suspect this is not what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry , i forgot to mention that i have already tried this
Does not help
Please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943563/how-to-make-api-test-files-with-beego)